# asp.net 5 (core 1) - getting authentication data in asp.net mvc web api seems different

Tags: asp.net-core

I am writing an application for a game where each user might have multiple characters. A user can only be working on or editing a single character at a time. Additionally, an administrator can login as a user in order to fix settings and such.

This works fine, but I find I have a lot of controller code dedicated just to retrieving the current character. Additionally, retrieving data on a character is something I want to abstract to an API so that other things can use it eventually.

So my thought for this was to create a `ApiController` to handle this data.

The problem is that retrieving data first needs to validate the logged in user. But I find that the `User` property doesn't persist `Identity` information in `ASP.NET MVC WebAPI` the same way as in normal places.

This is even more confusing to me because, as best I can see, there's no longer a difference in WebAPI and normal MVC. Both controller types inherit from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller`

But I get totally different results with this...

#### works fine

```c#
[Area("member")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the numeric identity of the currently logged in user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The numeric identity of the current user, or null if none is found.</returns>
    [Route("member/id")]
    public JsonResult Id() {
        // if the user is not authenticated, simply return false 
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
            return Json(false);
        return Json([...]);
    }
}
```

#### doesn't work

```c#
[Route("api/auth")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        // if the user is not authenticated, simply return false 
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
            return Json(false);
        // do something with the logged in user
        return Json([...]);
    }
}
```

I login using the normal `Identity` system, like this;

### login controller action

```c#
// ------------------------------
// <POST>: /account/login
// ------------------------------

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("account/login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // attempt to login with the requested credentials
        var result = await SignIn
                    .PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
        // if successful, the credentials are now stored in the identity system
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return Redirect("/");
        // if we reach this point, there was an error.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login credentials.");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

login works fine. I can access the `User.Identity` in normal controllers without issue. It's persisted in the browser if I tell it to. I literally have no problems with authentication in this respect.

But the moment I try to get the data from the `web api` controller, it's null. I can't figure out why, there should logically be nothing different about these two, right?

### Update

as requested, this is my `Identity` implementation in **Startup.cs**.

```c#
services.AddTransient<ILookupNormalizer>(s => new LowerInvariantLookupNormalizer());
services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<Player>>(s => new PasswordHasher<Player>());
services.AddIdentity<Player, Role>(o => {
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddUserStore<UserStore<Player>>()
.AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role>>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Could you please add implementation of the enabling identity in the Startup?

Comment: Sure, I've added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make authentication work with your web api, you have to implement token based authentication.

Have a look on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080508/1921440)

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.